# get-winevent -filterxpath vs select-xml

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, event-viewer, get-winevent

I'm trying to understand xpath better by trying the same thing in both select-xml and `Get-WinEvent`.  But some `Get-WinEvent` patterns don't seem to work in `Select-Xml`.  I get:

> expression must evaluate to a node-set

It works if I put "|" instead of the first "and".  I made an xml file from a windows log.  I guess you can't "and" two paths in the second command?  I guess it should be

```
*[System[EventID=4624] and EventData[Data [@Name='TargetUserName'] and Data='testuser']]
```

But `Get-WinEvent` is more forgiving.

```
# works ok (login event)
Get-WinEvent Security -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4624]] and 
  *[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName'] and Data='testuser']]"

# error
# "| select -expand node" if you want the xml object
select-xml "*[System[EventID=4624]] and 
  *[EventData[Data [@Name='TargetUserName'] and Data='testuser']]" event.xml

select-xml : Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
At line:1 char:2
+ select-xml "*[System[EventID=4624]] and *[EventData[Data [@Name='Tar ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Select-Xml], XPathException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Xml.XPath.XPathException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCommand
```

Here's a simplified event.xml:

```
<Event>
  <System>
    <EventID>4624</EventID> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">testuser</Data> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because they are not the same type of `XPath`. `Get-WinEvent` uses a **Filter** XPath (`-FilterXPath`), whereas `Select-XML` is a direct `-XPath` selection and you can't use either interchangeably.

I.e. `Get-WinEvent` you write a `XPath Filter` expression to filter (remove nodes from the document not matching the query).

For `Select-XML` you write an `XPath` expression to *Select* nodes to return. When the query is written that it can't figure out how to return a specific node, then you get the error

> Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

Because, indeed, you aren't returning a specific node.

Why the `|` worked is because `|` is the [Union (|) Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256074(v=vs.110).aspx). It is returning the Union of the two expressions. Indeed, if we split the expression in half, both expressions work on their own:

```
PS> select-xml "*[System[EventID=4624]]" event.xml

Node  Path        Pattern
----  ----        -------
Event InputStream *[EventData[Data [@Name='TargetUserName'] and Data='testuser']]

PS> select-xml " *[EventData[Data [@Name='TargetUserName'] and Data='testuser']]" event.xml

Node  Path        Pattern
----  ----        -------
Event InputStream *[EventData[Data [@Name='TargetUserName'] and Data='testuser']]
```

Because each half of the expression can be evaluated to target a specific node, it works. The Union just returns all nodes matching either of the expressions.

Comment: I don't know. And-ing two paths like "* and *" just seems like some kind of Microsoft extension or a mistake. I don't see it anywhere else.  You'll see it more often in windows log xml filters.